# php ProgressBar class displaying only 99% of completed jobs

Tags: php, for-loop

I am using the ProgressBar class from the following link for displaying a progress bar for image downloads..

http://pastebin.com/KSxjC01r

I am using the following code..

```
echo 'Starting Image Download...<br />';
$p = new ProgressBar();
echo '<div style="width: 300px;">';
$p->render();
echo '</div>';

//progress bar
for ($i = 0; $i < ($size = 100); $i++) {
$p->setProgressBarProgress($i*100/$size);
usleep(1000000*0.01);
 } 
fetch_image("$item", "../cbimages/$img ");
echo "Downloaded $img <br />";
}
echo "Finished downloading images....";
```

Everything is working fine..But for each download it is displaying only 99.0% in progress bar. After completion too it displays as **99.0%** . What is wrong the code above. Where am i going wrong. Help requested..

**Update:**

**Resolved the issue** by changing the following line in the class file:

**From:**

```
if ($percentDone == 100) {
print('document.getElementById("'.$this->pbid.'").style.display = "none";');
 }
```

**To:**

```
if ($percentDone == 100) {
print('document.getElementById("'.$this->pbid.'").style.width = "'.$percentDone.'%";');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **for** loop currently only counts to 99 because you used **<** instead of **<=**.

Changing it to this should work:

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i <= ($size = 100); $i++) {
    $p->setProgressBarProgress($i * 100 / $size);
    usleep(1000000 * 0.01);
}
```

Comment: I tried that early...But then the progress bar displays only for the first download...and does not display thereafter..Displays only Downloaded 1.jpg
Downloaded 2.jpg

Comment: Then it sounds like an issue with the JS in the file you included, which is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: @ Evan Darwin It is not javascript, but a php class. For most people the php class is working fine as seen from messages in the class website link:
http://spidgorny.blogspot.in/2012/02/progress-bar-for-lengthy-php-process.html

Comment: @user3790186 Looks like you're missing the `$p->setProgressBarProgress(100);` call after you finish the **for** loop.

Comment: I tried that too earlier...It will display only progress bar once.. and not for subsequent iterations..

Comment: Yet again, that sounds like an issue with the class and is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Do you mean discussing a php class is outside the scope of this question ??

Answer (score 0):

Your loop isn't quite right

you have this:

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < ($size = 100); $i++) {
```

The rule is that i < 100 so, when i == 100 the loop is not run. Meaning it is never passed to setProgressBarProgress()

This will work:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= ($size = 100); $i++) {
```

The loop will still run when i == 100

Comment: Please note that this is the same solution posted by evan above. I have tried it already and the progress bar then displays only the first download and not after that. Please read comments above..